# compilation Error in Task.ContinueWith when passing TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext as second parameter

Tags: task

```
private  void CountWithTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   lblOutput.Content = "file is in processing...";
   var taskInt = CountWords();
   taskInt.ContinueWith(x => 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("process has been done.");
      lblOutput.Content = $"count of words in file are :- {x.Result}";
      },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
   }
}
```

in the code snippet where I have return "x.Result",I am getting the compilation error at that point. and the error is [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYPKo.png)
"Task does not contain a definition for 'result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refernce?)"

if I remove that line then it is giving error at TaskScheduler, and the error is 
"Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method-group' to Cacellationtoken."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdVSt.png)

code for the CountWords method:

```
public async Task<int> CountWords()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format($"Thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()}"));
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            int count;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName);           
            var str = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            count = str.Length;
            reader.Close();

            return count;
        }
```

Comment: I assume that `CountWords()` returns just `Task`? Try making it `Task<int>` as only the generic version of `Task` has a `Result` property.

Comment: public async Task<int> CountWords()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format($"Thread ID: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()}"));
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            int count;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                var str = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                count = str.Length;
            }
            return count;
        }

Comment: this is the CountWords method @Scott.

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue the issue was very small my mistake and my negligence towards the intelligence. :)
     I am using only "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext", which is wrong becuase "FromCurrentSynchronizationContext" is a method and it should be like this "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()".

Proper code would be this :

```
private  void CountWithTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   lblOutput.Content = "file is in processing...";
   var taskInt = CountWords();
   taskInt.ContinueWith(x => 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("process has been done.");
      lblOutput.Content = $"count of words in file are :- {x.Result}";
      },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
   }
}
```

Thanks for the response @scott.

Thanks Stackoverflow.  :)

Comment: Oh ... what a misleading error message ! I could not figure out for 30 minutes ... Thank you !